# Unable to access to some files on Apache Server through URL

Tags: php, apache

`a_login.php` is located inside `includes/Views` under root directory. When I type http://test.mysite.com/includes/views/a_login.php I got 404 Error. If I move the file under root, http://test.mysite.com/a_login.php works fine. What would the reason be? Permission for all files and folders are the same.

Comment: are you using an MVC framework? what have you got in your htaccess? seems like you are using a router file

Comment: have you checked the logfiles? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log

Comment: Yes, MVC framework. I haven't created the site. Searched for htaccess file. It's not included.

Comment: Just noticed that the project has empty .pemhtaccess file.

Comment: @Jude what framework are you using? accessing the view like this won't/shouldn't work as this goes against the mvc framework entirely

Comment: MVC framework. Tried http://test.mysite.com/includes/controllers/login.php. Same.

Comment: Controllers with capital 'C' gives something like Fatal error: Call to a member function formstyle() on a non-object in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/102092/webspace/httpsdocs/SMART/includes/Controllers/login.php on line 4

Comment: @Jude which MVC framework? PHP has many i.e. ZendFramework, CakePHP, CodeIgniter... and the list goes on. The view is just the code that will create the look of your site. Your route file will redirect mysite.com/ to use the default.ctp for example and get the relevent controllers and models of that page